# C# Azure WebJobs 3.x with Azurite in local development

Tags: visual-studio, azure-webjobs, azurite

With .NET Core the WebJobs are now a [console application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs#webjobs-as-net-core-console-apps).

The new Azure Storage Emulator is [Azurite](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite).

The Visual Studio [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio) about the azurite mentions only how to setup the start of azurite in Azure Functions and ASP.NET projects.

Is there a way to automatically start Azurite, when debugging a WebJobs 3 project in Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the given [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#install-azurite)

> Azurite is automatically available with `Visual Studio 2022`.

AFAIK, for `.NET Console Apps`(Azure Web Jobs), there is no option to run the Azurite Automatically.
We need to start it manually from the Command Prompt.

Check whether `azurite.exe` is available in the mentioned path.

```cs
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\
```

[image]

- If you find the `.exe` file, then run the executable file
  [image]

[image]

***My App.config***

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="StorageConnection" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```